# Why can my two computers on the same hub not ping each other?

Tags: networking, ping

I have a pair of Windows XP computers that are connected by Ethernet cables to the same hub and they are in the same subnet (`10.1.10.0/24`), but they cannot ping each other. When I do attempt the ping, the requests time out but the arp cache gets an entry with the correct IP/MAC address pair. What could cause this to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the Windows firewall or a third party firewall turned on?  That would block ICMP.

Comment: This was the problem. The firewalls on both computers (McAfee in this case), were set up to block incoming ping requests.